# X-axis tick labels are too dense when drawing plots

Tags: python, matplotlib, axis, xticks

I am drawing matplotlib plots and my x axis consists of YYYYMM formatted strings of year and month like `201901` for January of 2019.

My problem is that some of the data spans on a long period of time and this makes the x axis tick labels so dense that they pile up on each other and they become unreadable.

I tried making the font smaller and I rotated the labels 90 degrees which helped a lot but it is still not enough for some of my data.

Here is an example of one of my x axis which looks ok:

[image: x-axis that looks fine]

And here is an example of an x axis which is too dense because the data spans on a long period of time:

[image: x-axis labels that are too dense]

So I want matplotlib to skip printing a few tick labels when the tick labels start piling up on each other. For example, print the label for January, skip printing the labels for February, March, April and May, print the label for June, and skip printing the labels for July, August etc. But I don't know how to do this?

Or are there any other kind of solutions I can use to overcome this problem?

Comment: Plot `datetime` objects instead of strings. Then the whole problem disappears.

Comment: Strings are treated as equally spaced “categories”.  If you put “boo” in there it would be treated the same as your other strings.  As @ImportanceOfBeingErnest says, it’s prererable to turn into datetimes so that the x values are treated as numbers.

Comment: Thanks for the feedbacks ImportanceOfBeingErnest, Jody.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

A quick dirty solution would be the following:

```py
ax.set_xticks(ax.get_xticks()[::2])
```

This would only display every *second* xtick. If you wanted to only display every *n-th* tick you would use

```py
ax.set_xticks(ax.get_xticks()[::n])
```

If you don't have a handle on `ax` you can get one as `ax = plt.gca()`.

Alternatively, you could specify the number of xticks to use with:

`plt.locator_params(axis='x', nbins=10)`

Comment: perfect answer, precise and concise.

Comment: Quick and dirty wins the race

Answer (score 13):

An alternate solution could be as below:

```
x = df['Date']
y = df['Value']

# Risize the figure (optional)    
plt.figure(figsize=(20,5))
    
# Plot the x and y values on the graph
plt.plot(x, y)
    
# Here you specify the ticks you want to display
# You can also specify rotation for the tick labels in degrees or with keywords.
plt.xticks(x[::5],  rotation='vertical')

# Add margins (padding) so that markers don't get clipped by the axes
plt.margins(0.2)

# Display the graph
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Where do you read the excel file on the above code?

Comment: @just_learning... The excel file is read in df. Use df = pandas.read_excel("pathToExcelFile")

Comment: Plus vote for the rotation :)