# matplotlib how to display large data points to smaller size

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I  have many y-axis values let's say 8000, these 8000 values are all necessary ,and if I plot them into a line graph, I would get 1 to 8000 in some ticks, which is too large. I  want to change the 1 to 8000 into 1 to 12 without losing any y-axis values, what shall I do ?

Here is an example graph which I have already got.
Imgur link: https://i.stack.imgur.com/s8ClN.jpg

```py
pmValue_2010 =PRSA_data.iloc[1:8762,5]
year = range(1,8762) 

plt.plot(year,pmValue_2010)

plt.show()
```

I want to change to a graph like this

Imgur link: https://i.stack.imgur.com/59ydF.jpg
as you can see, the x-axis with different formats, all I want to do is change them into  a certain range and do not lose any value of the y-axis

Sorry, not enough rep to post image here.

Comment: Use the stack overflow image hosting instead of regular imgur. Post links to images, not galleries.

Comment: Can I just clarify, you only want to reduce the number of labels and tick marks whilst plotting the same actual line plot to the graph?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [X-axis tick labels are too dense when drawing plots with matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54783160/x-axis-tick-labels-are-too-dense-when-drawing-plots-with-matplotlib)

Comment: `plt.plot(year/8762*12, pmValue_2010)` ?

Answer (score 0):

You could put something like this before `plt.show()`:

```py
locs, _ = plt.xticks()
plt.xticks(locs[::500])
```

This gets a list of the current x-tick/label locations and sets them to every 500 in the list.